# Enable icons in listpicker

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm having a problem with the listpicker (SelectionMode="Multiple"!!!). When i go to fullmode it doesnt show "done", "cancel" icons like if the images were not in my project.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="2" Name="ListPickerAu" Header="" FullModeHeader="Authority Assessment"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple" FontSize="21" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Margin="10,12,-157,12" >
                            <sys:String>Order</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>Distribute</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>Price</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>Merchandise</sys:String>
                        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

How can I enable that buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have **Toolkit.Content** folder in your project? That's where these icons should be. Did you use NuGet to include Toolkit into you project or downloaded it manually?

Comment: I don't have Toolkit.Content folder in my project. How can I add that?

Comment: My recommendation is to remove your reference to Toolkit library and add Toolkit by NuGet. Then this folder will be created automatically.

Comment: Sorry. Im new to WP apps. How to add Toolkit by NuGet?

Comment: To add Toolkit by NuGet: right-click on your project in SolutinExplorer and click **Manage NuGet Packages...** Then search "wptoolkit" and install.